# change timer to 3 decimal places

Tags: function, timer, lua, coronasdk

I have a count down timer that starts from 3 and counts down to 0. I am trying to get it to displays the timer to 3 decimal places. So that user can see the milliseconds count down. for example: `2.765` etc.

```
local function choice ( event )
    randCircle = circle[ math.random( #circle ) ]
    randCircle:setFillColor(1,0,0);

    local timeLimit = 3.000
        timeLeft = display.newText(timeLimit, randCircle.x, randCircle.y, native.systemFontBold, 36)
        timeLeft:setTextColor( 0,0,0 )
        sceneGroup:insert( timeLeft )

        local function timerDown()
           timeLimit = timeLimit - 1
           timeLeft.text = timeLimit
             if( timeLimit == 0 )then
                print( "Time Out" ) -- or do your code for time out
            end
        end
    aTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000,timerDown,timeLimit ) 

end
timer.performWithDelay( 2000, choice, 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
display.newText(string.format("%.3f",timeLimit),...
```